# Show hide left navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a menu that is located on the left side of the screen, and with a button that is located on the main content area i hide/show the menu.

When the screen width is less than 768px i hide the menu using css, the problem that im having is that because the menu is already hided, when the user clicks on the button instead of showing the menu it is trying to hide the menu again.

Im having a lot of troubles trying to explain the problem, 
Here is the live demo, with all the code of what I have.

The code works fine for desktop, the problem is when the screen is less that 768px.

This is the function tham using to show/hide the menu and to move the content

```
  $('#menu-toggle').click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('show-hide');
    $('#page-content').toggleClass('show-hide');
  });
```

CSS

```
.show-hide
{
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Full Code Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c7cpLq9m/

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @lonut https://jsfiddle.net/c7cpLq9m/

Comment: You saw the big, red warning box that said you needed to post a [mcve] in your question when linking to jsFiddle, yet you went out of your way to get around that. Just do as you are asked and post your code in your question.

Comment: Your example works for me?

Comment: @Christoph try making the screen smaller(less than 768px)

Comment: @j08691 I don't know what are you talking about... but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added this to the media query:

```
#wrapper .show-hide {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```js
$('#menu-toggle, .mobile-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('show-hide');
  $('#page-content').toggleClass('show-hide');
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.mobile-trigger{
  display: none;
}
#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #1b1e24;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.show-hide {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

ul.sidebar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: #8b91a0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

ul.sidebar-nav li span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

ul.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

#page-content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* position: absolute;     */
  padding-left: 255px;
  /* width:100%;    
 background: grey;*/
}

@media ( max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #wrapper .show-hide{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .mobile-trigger{
    display: block;
  }
  #page-content {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
     <li><a class='mobile-trigger' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Hide mobile menu</a></li>
      <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> Inbound</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Outbound</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Social</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Duis aute</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" style="float:rigth">Toggle Menu</a>
          <h1>Duis aute</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <h1>Excepteur</h1>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
```

**Update**:

On mobile is better if you not push the content because it will look very messy. It's better to have the menu over the content and add a button inside the menu to close it. For this I added an extra element inside the menu, added the class `mobile-trigger`, I've hidden it by default on desktop and showed it on mobile using `display: block;`. Also added the selector `mobile-trigger` to the click event.

Comment: Not working properly and no explanation provided. Please improve your code accordingly. The navigation overlaps the main text and cannot be hidden again.

Comment: @Christoph, I don't think that on mobile it needs to push the content if you catch my drift. Not at least on smartphones.

Comment: I 100% agree, but you need a possibility to minimize the the menu again^_^ A close button within the nav would be most appropriate I guess.

Comment: @Christoph, yes, added a button inside the menu on mobile only. I hope it helps the OP.

Comment: Perhaps add this to your answer as well. Awesome job otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

In lonut's answer its better adding this styles:

```
#menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
```

To bring the toggle menu button top right of page.